# What's wrong with this jQuery click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, button

I'm currently working on a pretty goofy project, just to get a my foot into the door of jQuery. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$("#buyOne").click(function() {
    one++;
    var costOne = 10;
    if (coins - costOne < 0) {
        alert("Dogs ain't free, ya know!");
    } else {
        dogs += 1;
        coins -= costOne;
        $("#main").html("You have " + coins + " coins.");

        var levelOne = $("<div></div>", {
            "class" : "levelOne dog one"+one
        })

        $("body").append(levelOne);

        var battleOne = $("<button class='battleOne'>Send dog to battle</button>");

        $(".one"+one).append(battleOne);
    }
});

$(".battleOne").click(function() {
    coins += 1;
    alert("Your dog won the battle! + 1 coin");
});
```

Sorry about the funky StackOverflow formatting, but my problem is that the click function on `.battleOne` isn't working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: use event delegation. use  `$(document).one("click",".battleOne",function() {`

Comment: What is not working? Is the event not firing?

Comment: if you use `.` you are adding click function to all object that contain class `battleOne`. I think you must declare it using ID which is `#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var battleOne = $("<button class='battleOne'>Send dog to battle</button>");

$(".one").click(function() {
  $('body').append(battleOne);

});

$(document).on("click",".battleOne",function() {
  alert("Your dog won the battle! + 1 coin");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='one'>add</button>
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!